# jQuery - Simple way to select a table row

Tags: jquery

I am creating an html table dynamically.

`$('#facilityModalTable').append('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');`

There will be an `<input type=Button value=Select />` on each row.  I want to get all the `row` data in the clicked Select buttons `row`.  I can think of a few options, but I'm not sure which to go with.

1. Create `data-uniqueid` attributes and assign to each column in a row.
2. Somehow use `siblings()` to solve the problem.
3. Other...

What do you recommend?

Comment: What do you mean by row data? Contents of each `<td>`?

Comment: @Sahil Muthoo - Yes, each sibling `td` has a single `div` with html.  I want the html of each sibling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the *simplest* way to do it, but this is how I'd probably approach it just off the top of my head:

```
$("#facilityModalTable").append('<tr><td><input type="Button" value="Select"/></td><td>Hello</td><td>Red</td><td>12345</td><td>Buffalo, NY</td></tr>').find("input[type=button]").bind("click", function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
    arrData = [];
    $this.parent().siblings().each(function (i, cell) {
        arrData[i] = $(cell).text();
    });
});
```

In this code I added the button and filled in some values just for testing purposes. I'm making some assumptions here so forgive me if something's not quite aligned with what you're trying to do.

I wouldn't be surprised if there was a faster, more efficient way to do this. This is just off the top of my head in about a minute.

Cheers!

Comment: I went with this solution over `closest` for two reasons.  1.  As a rule I don't nest tables.  2.  This solutions breaks up the `td` data in a consistent fashion.  Unlike closest, where the data is compiled into a single string.  I would need to implement a method to break-up the data myself, definitely non-trivial.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).closest('tr');
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Unlike `parents()`, `closest()` travels up the DOM tree *until* it finds a match for the supplied selector. `parents('tr')` travels up to the document's root element, possibly selecting other table rows, in case of nested tables.

Comment: jQuery's parent() method is significantly more efficient than its closest() method in this particular scenario and even a scenario involving going up several levels of the DOM tree mainly because parent() simply invokes native DOM traversing code while closest() invokes a number of nested conditionals.

Comment: @natlee75: Good to know. I often go for closest() in order to allow for more flexible markup, but if you know what to except parent() seems to be the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**simple :**

```
$(this).parents("tr:first").css('border','solid 1px red');
```

whenever a clicked item inside the TR - it goes u and search for its TR parent and then...

Comment: This code works, but it is less efficient than using parent() in this particular scenario where you know that you're trying to get the data out of the direct parent's siblings.

Comment: The parent() method simply returns the parentNode of the element. The parents() method executed even on a direct child invokes a number of lines of code including but not limited to the declaration of an array, two layers of conditional testing, a push to the declared array, and a variable assignment.